# Active improving of nanodiamond surfaces for NV centers?

Tags: architecture, experimental-realization, solid-state, nv-centers

This question is related (and complementary) to "[Passive improving of nanodiamond surfaces for NV centers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/passive-improving-of-nanodiamond-surfaces-for-nv-centers)".

[Nitrogen-Vacancy centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen-vacancy_center) (NVs) have astonishing quantum properties, which make them interesting as potential hardware both for quantum computing in particular and for quantum technologies in general. In part this results from the center being protected by the diamond structure, which is at the same time very rigid and practically free from nuclear spins.

However, their surfaces tend to be far from controlled. Neither in *chemical* terms (composition, structure) not in terms of what it contributes to the *physical properties of the bulk*. For example, in experiments of diamond levitation using lasers, at high powers of irradiation, the diamonds typically get noticeably lighter (and thus oscillate further in their potential wells) as they suddenly (and uncontrolledly lose the external rubbish.

Coming closer to the question: in these same experiments, even though diamonds are essentially transparent to the lasers employed for the levitation, eventually at high laser power and low pressure diamonds overheat and essentially *evaporate*. Since these conditions are useful to fix the diamonds in place and reduce noise, this is a problem for the control of NV centers as qubits for quantum computing purposes. One reason for the poor thermal dissipation in diamonds -which in absence of gas that can carry convection necessarily happens via black body radiation- is the fact that the phonon spectrum of diamond is essentially empty: covalent bonds are too strong, everything is fix in its place, and there is nothing available that can vibrate.

My question is, since heat release is often governed by surface properties, what is the current status of efforts to alter diamond surface with the goal of obtaining **spectrally selective thermal emittance properties**, meaning emitting preferentially at energies below the evaporation of the diamond starts?